# Form Duplicates When Opened

Tags: c#, winforms

So basically, I'm having this issue where when Form1 Goes away and it should display Form2, but for some reason Form2 Opens twice. Video on the situation: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/531630309880627200/625753886153506851/Desktop_2019.09.23_-_20.00.10.03.mp4

My Code:

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Hide();
            Main_Form MainForm = new Main_Form();
            MainForm.Show();
            timer1.Stop();
        }
```

Comment: Maybe stop the timer first.  Why use a timer at all, by the way?

Comment: I've tried that, didn't change a thing. The reason I use a timer is because once the First form hides (Form1 is sort of like a splash screen) I want to open the second Form (Main Form)

Comment: We would have to see more of your code that duplicates it.  This is a fairly well known topic, so googling should get you lots of results.

Comment: [link](https://i.imgur.com/gQ7woU6.png)

Comment: We don't do links or pictures of code around here.  Edit your question with the text version.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Main_Form MainForm;

private void SwitchForms()
{
    this.Hide();
    if (MainForm == null) {
        MainForm = new Main_Form()
        MainForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Use this code instead of timer function if you have the same result, then the problem is not here, you need to look from another place.